# How to launch GUI app via sh

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to my app launch itself after install.I am not sure whether this is true.I note that pxl files usually has the postflight file and it contains "launch" chars and it relating a plist file.So,Can I launch my GUI app via some sh commandline ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just launch it like any other app.

Comment: Could you tell me some more information?I just want to make effect as the springboard but no launch it via touch springboardico.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible on a jailbroken iPhone, I don't know. But for a non-jailbroken iPhone, this is definitely impossible and no attempt to make it work would be approved for inclusion in the App Store.

Comment: YES,I run it on a jailbroken iPhone.